# Change the href of uisref with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I would like to override the functionality of the uiSref, I need that instead of generating the state URL add something based on some conditions, for example

let's say that I have this

`<a ui-sref="mystate">link</a>`

that end with

`<a href="#!/path/to/state">link</a>`

I would like to add something like this

`<a href="http://otherdomain/#!/path/to/state">link</a>`

the idea is not to create a custom directive, is to use the already use of ui-sref, I read about decorators, but don't have an idea how to apply this the ui-sref directive.

Some help, please

UPDATE

The only solution that came up is to, after the state resolve, find all the tag `<a>` and manually change the href, but i found that a little tricky

Comment: Dislike this idea as you can not use most of Ui-sref features for another domain. Better create your own directive

Comment: what about `ng-href` idea with `"http://otherdomain/{{ path }}"`?

Comment: I already have an entire application using uisref, change that would be a lot of work. @AlekseySolovey

Comment: @stalin what about rewriting the source code for `uiSref` directive?